# Wordpress Searches outside of Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I recently added a new installation of WordPress to a new directory on my site. Everything seems to be working fine except the search function.

When I search for something it searches and then displays results (or lack thereof) in my home directory install of WordPress.

So when I go to **mysite.com/freshinstall** and do a search it displays 
 results at **mysite.com/?s=searchtest&x=0&y=0** instead of **mysite.com/freshinstall/?s=searchtest&x=0&y=0**

This is my Search Form.

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly set the new WordPress installations search form element action property from:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
```

to this:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/" method="get">
```

The WordPress bloginfo('url') function outputs the “Site address (URL)” set in Settings > General options of your new WordPress installation for use by the action property helping the search results stay within the sub-directory WordPress installation.